# Whats the implication of SSD Capacity for a server running Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, heroku, bonsai-elasticsearch

I'm evaluating Bonsai Elastic Search packages to run my elastic search operations but I don't understand all plan specifications. What are the implications of SSD capacity?

Source: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bonsai

I've researched that SSD = solid state drive, but I don't understand what that means in this context.

What is "SSD capacity" in the context of a server running elastic search and when would it need to be increased?

[image]

Comment: *capacity* when related to a storage device means size. 100GB provides twice the capacity as 50GB. Researching plans is not a programming related question according to this site's guidelines, however. You should be addressing questions regarding their plans to that vendor.

Comment: Some useful info as to why SSD is recommended for operating ES: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#_storage